# Is the Cloud Simulation service still running

Tags: cloudsim

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

I saw that a Cloud Simulation feature is listed on the Gazebo home page but the link http://cloudsim.io/ hasn't worked for me across the couple of days I've tried it. Is it sill available?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/13253/is-the-cloud-simulation-service-still-running/) by [azaclauson](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/2592/azaclauson/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 35 on 2016-05-10

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

It is on our roadmap for Gazebo 8.0, and is under development. Stay tuned.

---

Originally posted by [nkoenig](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/5/nkoenig/) with karma: 7676 on 2016-05-10

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0